# Retrieve video files - Sony remote camera API

Tags: android, video-capture, sony

In the Sony remote camera API, it is possible to take a photo and retrieve it from a given URL. It is also possible to record a video to the camera (see the Sony developer pages at http://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/ for how). Is it possible to retrieve that video from the camera after it has been recorded?

See [this question](https://camera.developer.sony.com/common/forum/en/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=130&sid=87d8f6e4a2b53178e4d30000b08ee6e6) on the Sony Developer forums.

The current PlayMemories Mobile allows you to transfer the files from the camera, however I do not see any API command to retrieve video files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently at this time there is no API to retrieve a video file.