# Video thumbnail - Sony remote camera API

Tags: android, video, thumbnails, video-capture, sony

I am developing an app that uses the Sony remote camera API to record videos. I am using a minor variation of the sample app provided (currently v1.21, if that makes any difference). I understand from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20998439/retrieve-video-files-sony-remote-camera-api) that you cannot yet pull videos from the device. I noticed that in the documentation for stopMovieRec, the response should contain a url to a thumbnail (which would be a small consolation):

```
{ 
    "result": [ 
        "http://ip:port/thumbnail/thumbnail.jpg" 
    ], 
    "id": 1 
}
```

However, when I log the response from stopMovieRec, I get an empty string. Is this feature not enabled? Not enabled on certain devices? I have tested on the HDR-AS30 and DSC-QX10. Maybe my code is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your inquiry and investigation.
I am sorry. This thumbnail feature is not supported in Camera Remote API beta currently.
We will post an update when it becomes available.

Regards,
Prem from Sony